# Go | efficient and readable way to append a slice and send to variadic function

Tags: go, slice, prepend

Let's say I have the following pipeline of functions:

```
func func3(opts ...FunctionObject) {
    for _, opt := range opts {
        opt()
    }
}

func func2(opts ...FunctionObject) {
   var functions []FunctionObject
   functions = append(functions, someFunction3)
   functions = append(functions, someFunction4)
...
...
...
    func3(append(functions, opts...)...)
}


func func1(opts ...FunctionObject) {
   var functions []FunctionObject
   functions = append(functions, someFunction)
   functions = append(functions, someFunction2)
...
...
...
    func2(append(functions, opts...)...)
}
```

For reasons inherited in the problem I want to solve, the functions in `functions` should be called before the functions in `opts` , so i can't just append to `opts` but I have to *prepend* `functions` to `opts` (by `append(functions, opts...)` ) and then using `...` again to send it to next function in the pipeline, so im getting the weird expression:

```
func2(append(functions, opts...)...)
```

I don't know how efficient it is, but Im sure it looks weird,
There must be a better way of doing it, and that's what Im looking for.

yet i'd be grateful for accompanying explanation about efficiency :)

Edit:
I can't change the the argument type from `opts ...FunctionObject` to `opts []FunctionObject` (as @dev.bmax suggested in comments) since im making changes in an existing codebase so i can't change the functions that call `func{1,2,3}`

2. by saying that "it looks weird" i don't mean only of the "look" but it looks weird to do this operation (ellipsis) twice, and it seems to be inefficient (am i wrong?)

Comment: Did you try to change the argument type from `opts ...FunctionObject` to `opts []FunctionObject`? This gets rid of the second ellipsis.

Comment: *"it's ugly"* -- Then use `functions = append(functions, opts...)`; `func2(functions...)`; Or you could also write a generic function that joins a variadic number of slices. E.g. `func2(join(functions, opts)...)`.

Comment: @dev.bmax I can't, Im revising an existing code and i can't change the other places that call to `func1` etc. i can only add arguments that will not require all the callers to change their calls

Comment: @mkopriva I meant that the idea to do so sounds weird, eve if you split it into 2 statements.
anyway, I change the wording in the questions, as well as added information

Comment: @danwgh dotdotdot-twice can be spotted here and there in the standard library as well. *"it seems to be inefficient"* -- depending on what `func1` is actually doing there may perhaps be ways to optimize the code; but given two separate slices that you need joined and then passed to a variadic function then doing what you're doing is the way to go. Note also that doing `func2(s...)` will just copy `s`, it is effectively the same as if you had `func func2(p []T)` and you called the function as `func2(s)`.

Comment: A new slice with a backing array is created only when you are passing individual arguments, e.g. `func2(a,b,c,d)`, but when you're doing `func2(s...)`, then no new slice/array is created, only copy of `s` is created, which is **not** inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepending to a slice is fundamentally inefficient since it will require some combination of:

- allocating a larger backing array
- moving items to the end of the slice
- ...or both.

It would be more efficient if you could change the calling convention between functions to only append options and then process them in reverse. This could avoid repeatedly moving items to the end of the slice and potentially all allocations beyond the first (if enough space is allocated in advance).

```
func func3(opts ...FunctionObject) {
    for i := len(opts) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        opts[i]()
    }
}
```

Note: `func3(opts ...FunctionObject) / func3(opts...)` and `func3(opts []FunctionObject) / func3(opts)` are equivalent for performance. The former is effectively syntactic sugar for passing the slice.

However, you've mentioned you need to keep your calling conventions...

Your example code will cause allocations for the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th,.. append within each function - allocations are needed to double the size of the backing array (for small slices). `append(functions, opts...)` will likely also allocate if the earlier appends didn't create enough spare capacity.

A helper function could make the code more readable. It could also reuse spare capacity in the `opts` backing array:

```golang
func func2(opts ...FunctionObject) {
    // 1-2 allocations. Always allocate the variadic slice containings 
    // prepend items. Prepend reallocates the backing array for `opts`
    // if needed.
    opts = Prepend(opts, someFunction3, someFunction4)
    func3(opts...)
}

// Generics requires Go1.18+. Otherwise change T to FunctionObject.
func Prepend[T any](base []T, items ...T) []T {
    if size := len(items) + len(base); size <= cap(base) {
        // Extend base using spare slice capacity.
        out := base[:size]
        // Move elements from the start to the end of the slice (handles overlaps).
        copy(out[len(items):], base)
        // Copy prepended elements.
        copy(out, items)
        return out
    }
    return append(items, base...) // Always re-allocate.
}
```

Some alternate options without the helper function that describe the allocations in more detail:

```golang
// Directly allocate the items to prepend (2 allocations).
func func1(opts ...FunctionObject) {
    // Allocate slice to prepend with no spare capacity, then append re-allocates the backing array
    // since it is not large enough for the additional `opts`.
    // In future, Go could allocate enough space initially to avoid the
    // reallocation, but it doesn't do it yet (as of Go1.20rc1).
    functions := append([]FunctionObject{
        someFunction,
        someFunction2,
        ...
    }, opts...)
    // Does not allocate -- the slice is simply passed to the next function.
    func2(functions...)
}

// Minimise allocations (1 allocation).
func func2(opts ...FunctionObject) {
   // Pre-allocate the required space to avoid any further append
   // allocations within this function.
   functions := make([]FunctionObject, 0, 2 + len(opts))
   functions = append(functions, someFunction3)
   functions = append(functions, someFunction4)
   functions = append(functions, opts...)
   func3(functions...)
}
```

You could go further and reuse with spare capacity in `opts` without needing to allocate a slice containing the items to prepend (0-1 allocations per function). However this is complex and error prone -- I wouldn't recommend it.